# How to resolve screen ghosting issue in Kindle?

Tags: kindle, kindle-kdk

I am using KRepaintManager.paintImmediately(root, true) from  start() in my main class that extends AbstractKindlet to refresh the screen, but there are still ghosting issue there. When pressing and dismissing Menu - the screen clears up. I am wondering what code is doing after the Menu is dismissed?

How to resolve ghosting issue Kindle device?

Code:

```
KPages pages = new KPages() {
        /**
         * A place holder serialization version ID
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        /** {@inheritDoc} */
        public Insets getInsets() {
            return new Insets(00, 20, 20, 20);
        }
};

public static void flashScreen()
{
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){ 
        public void run(){
            KRepaintManager.currentManager(pages).addDirtyRegion(pages, 0, 0, pages.getWidth(), pages.getHeight());
            KRepaintManager.currentManager(pages).paintDirtyRegions(true);
        }
    });

}
```

Calling flashScreen() while back, forward navigation of KPages.

Comment: Is it actually flashing the screen when you do that?

Comment: Yes, It is for flashing the screen. I have used KPages component. I wanted to flash whole screen while page navigation takes place.

Comment: I'm saying, is it actually flashing the screen, though? Do you see the entire screen flash

Comment: No, I could not see entire screen flash.

Comment: Are you developing this for the touch or the other devices? do you see anythign flash?

Comment: No, it's not for touch, I am developing with Kindlet-1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`KRepaintManager.paintImmediately(root, true)` is the correct way to flash the entire screen -- sometimes you'll end up with artifacts, still, but there's nothing you can do to prevent that. Hitting the `Menu` button in general will refresh the screen similarly.

Comment: Thank you so much for solution. 
I have used KPages Component. This component contains 100 pages. Each page contains UI. While navigating through pages, I can see ghosting on screen. During back and forward navigation, I wanted to repaint the screen.